# Why doesn't WASM memory utilisation show up in Chrome developer tools "performance tab"?

Tags: google-chrome, webassembly

I had a memory leak in my application (due to using a [library which introduces it through WASM](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1937)). This seems to cause crashes after a few minutes, and I didn't realise there was even a memory leak at first because the performance tab indicated `HEAP` utilisation was low: in the screenshot, it ranged from 9.8MB to 44.0MB.

However, when I captured a heap dump of the memory (under the memory tab), I noticed that I had 1939MB of memory.

Why doesn't the `performance` tab capture the same information as the memory tab. It looks like this behaviour is not documented anywhere?

**EDIT:** Updated after realising where the memory leak was coming from: **WASM**.

[image]